# Linkedin app transfer and app status

Tags: linkedin-api

First question: Can i change ownership of a linkedin app to another linkedin account? How can I start a transfer when possible?

And second question: what happens effectively when you change the status of an app from development to live? We are using this particular app already in kind of a production mode (and we do not want to lose the current functionality!

Thanks in advance!